# Android Studio Flutter - Virtual Device in Loading or stuck

Tags: android, flutter, loading

When opening Android Studio and trying to run my first demo app of flutter.
The device section continues to show loading; even when the emulator is on.

[image: android studio loading virtual device stuck.]

The error I get when I click on loading & try to choose virtual device.

```
Error Opening Emulator
            emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.
            Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think thats a bug from android studio but you can start you emulator by going to the avd manager:

[image]

and starting or creating it from there:

[image]

hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:
terminal Android Studio

```
taskkill /F /IM dart.exe
```